# Master/Slave in MySQL (Ubuntu & OSX)

Tags: mysql, macos, ubuntu

I'm setting up a Master/Slave in MySQL. I have local network with one Ubuntu and one iMac with OSX El Capitan.

The MySQL in Ubuntu is the Master and my.cnf i set the following:

```
[mysqld]  
log-bin = mysql-bin  
server-id=1 
innodb_flush_
log_at_trx_commit=1  
sync_binlog=1
```

In OSX (Slave) I could guess that my.cnf must be placed in /etc/ due to as I could read, MySQL init with default configuration. So, I stopped the service and created the file /etc/my.cnf with the following:

```
[mysqld]
server-id=2

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Restart the service and in console I set the following:

```
mysql> CHANGE MASTER TO
    -> MASTER_HOST='192.168.1.133',
    -> MASTER_USER='slave_user',
    -> MASTER_PASSWORD='slave_password',
    -> MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
    -> MASTER_LOG_POS=154; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 2 warnings (0,09 sec)
```

The question is that it does not work and as can be seen in the console result, it arises two warnings I'm not able to find due to the location of files in OSX are complete different than a normal installation of MySQL.

Anyone can help?

EDIT:

```
mysql> show master status;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |  1106753 |              |                  |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Master position is increasing due to its working...

```
mysql> show slave status;
+----------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------------+------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Slave_IO_State       | Master_Host   | Master_User | Master_Port | Connect_Retry | Master_Log_File  | Read_Master_Log_Pos | Relay_Log_File                | Relay_Log_Pos | Relay_Master_Log_File | Slave_IO_Running | Slave_SQL_Running | Replicate_Do_DB | Replicate_Ignore_DB | Replicate_Do_Table | Replicate_Ignore_Table | Replicate_Wild_Do_Table | Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table | Last_Errno | Last_Error | Skip_Counter | Exec_Master_Log_Pos | Relay_Log_Space | Until_Condition | Until_Log_File | Until_Log_Pos | Master_SSL_Allowed | Master_SSL_CA_File | Master_SSL_CA_Path | Master_SSL_Cert | Master_SSL_Cipher | Master_SSL_Key | Seconds_Behind_Master | Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert | Last_IO_Errno | Last_IO_Error                                                                            | Last_SQL_Errno | Last_SQL_Error | Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids | Master_Server_Id | Master_UUID | Master_Info_File                                         | SQL_Delay | SQL_Remaining_Delay | Slave_SQL_Running_State                                | Master_Retry_Count | Master_Bind | Last_IO_Error_Timestamp | Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp | Master_SSL_Crl | Master_SSL_Crlpath | Retrieved_Gtid_Set | Executed_Gtid_Set | Auto_Position | Replicate_Rewrite_DB | Channel_Name | Master_TLS_Version |
+----------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------------+------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Connecting to master | 192.168.1.133 | slave_user  |        3306 |            60 | mysql-bin.000001 |                1166 | iMac-de-MAVA-relay-bin.000002 |             4 | mysql-bin.000001      | Connecting       | Yes               |                 |                     |                    |                        |                         |                             |          0 |            |            0 |                1166 |             154 | None            |                |             0 | No                 |                    |                    |                 |                   |                |                  NULL | No                            |          2003 | error connecting to master 'slave_user@192.168.1.133:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 25 |              0 |                |                             |                0 |             | /usr/local/mysql-5.7.15-osx10.11-x86_64/data/master.info |         0 |                NULL | Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates |              86400 |             | 161007 11:58:08         |                          |                |                    |                    |                   |             0 |                      |              |                    |
+----------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------------------+------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------+----------------------+--------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: does not work mean? do "show master status;" on master and "show slave status;" on slave.. what do you see?

Comment: Ok. I posted both Master & Slave Statues. Now I'm realizing that Slave does not connect to master.

Comment: And use `show warnings` to see the warnings

Comment: And this question would be more suitable for DBAs than sw developers.

Comment: it says: "error connecting to master 'slave_user@192.168.1.133:3306' either salve can't reach/resolve master, or master does not have the user record!

Comment: @krishKM, Yes, I could realized that the connection was refused due to the Master lack of bind-address setting. Thanks!